# What does this mean? Not ones requiring explicit verbal descriptions

Tags: meaning

> Demonstrations of infants' and toddlers' long-term memory have involved their repeating motor activities that they had seen or done earlier, such as reaching in the dark for objects, putting a bottle in a doll's mouth, or pulling apart two pieces of a toy. The brain's level of physiological maturation may support these types of memories, but not ones requiring explicit verbal descriptions.

Does the quote "but not ones requiring explicit verbal descriptions." mean memorizing these motor actions does not need verbal description or does the author convey this hypothesis has no concrete evidence?

Comment: *...but [the brain's level of physiological maturation] does **not** support the **types of memories that** require explicit verbal descriptions.*

Comment: In other words, babies can remember actions they learned earlier but not things that have to be put into words.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of *ellipsis* ([see Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))). It can be rephrased as follows:

> The brain's level of physiological maturation may support these types of memories. But the brain's level of physiological maturation does not support ones [i.e., memories] requiring explicit verbal descriptions.

*Edit:* "Ones" is not the ellipsis. The ellipsis is the omission of "the brain's level of physiological maturation" and "support" after the conjunction

Comment: That’s not ellipsis; *ones* is a pronoun with the antecedent noun *memories*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "ones" is not the ellipsis. The ellipsis is the omission of "the brain's level of physiological maturation does" and "support" after the conjunction.

Comment: (The comma in the original makes it clear that these are intended to be read as two separate independent clauses, so ellipsis explains why part of the second clause is omitted.)

Comment: "Ellipsis" is not a technical term; it just means "something's missing". This particular deletion is called _Conjunction Reduction_, because it requires a conjunction like _but_ and parallel structure on both sides.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ellipsis [is used as a technical term in linguistics](https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/display/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0218.xml); as e.g. [this article explains](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/4/80387/files/2020/01/Wilder-OxHBEllips.pdf), conjunction reduction is considered a type of ellipsis.

Comment: Since ellipsis of any sort is rule-governed, the general term is of little use for people who are interested in the rules. Normally they're called "deletion rules", as one of the big 3 things you can do to a constituent: delete it or a part of it, move it or a part of it (by movement rules, natch), or add something to it (insertion rules). There are [hundreds of such rules](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), all with different effects and different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The verb phrase is the key, once you fill in the blanks:

> *may support [these types of memories],
>
> but (may) not (support) [[ones]
>
> [requiring explicit verbal descriptions]]*

This is straightforward Conjunction Reduction, deleting *may* and *support* after *but*. Clearly the pronoun *ones* refers back to *these types of memories*, expanding to *memories that require explicit verbal descriptions*, which are by assertion not the same types of memories as *these types*.